# Нужен SD_SEND для UDP соединения?

Tags: c++, c, udp, winsock

Есть такой код, как я понял он полностью отключает соединения, мне интересно для чего его используют в UDP сети. Или его вообще не используют и он предназначен только для TCP.

```
shutdown(clientSocket, SD_SEND);
```

Comment: [further transmissions will be disallowed](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shutdown.2.html)  (`SD_SEND` это наверное в винде? Там должно быть так же). Т.е. если вы хотите ловить в программе ошибки использования `send` после некоторого события, то можете использовать, а на практике -- не нужно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shutdown` запрещает прием и / или отправку сообщений по определенному сокету до его закрытия. Никакого соединения (которого в UDP нет) он не отключает (хотя в случае TCP при этом может отсылаться FIN, то бишь перевод соединения в полузакрытое состояния). Обычно этот метод бывает полезен для вызова в момент, когда все последующие данные должны будут приходить только с одной стороны для экономии ресурсов.

Comment: А как восстановить соединения после SD_SEND, есть команда?

Comment: @grob Такая возможность отсутствует.